# How can i read folder names?

Tags: php, directory

i have a folder named categories which has lots of folder inside.I need to take those names and insert into database.

is there any function or way that takes folder names with php?

Comment: [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple RTM would have got you: [readdir()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    /* This is the WRONG way to loop over the directory. */
    while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Be sure to read the documentation for the gotchas!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all folder name with this code

```
<?php
    $dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
    print_r( $dirs);
?>
```

Comment: Try this code and u will get all directory name in array.